# Compare if a string match then set var to double javascript

Tags: javascript

[Check the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPv6F.png)

I have an input table like those and i want to input string to Nilai. i.e I input string "A" to Nilai, it must read as 5. i.e A = 5, B = 4 and C= 3.

in the image above SKS is 3 and Nilai is A, then the N*S must be 15. so how can it read A as 5, B as 4, and C as 3?

i have tried it with if statement but it seems doesn't work or is it possible to do this in javascript.

here is my code

```html
<form name="ips">
<div class="inputan">
<input type="text" value="SKS" disabled="">
<input type="text" value="Nilai" disabled="">
<input type="text" value="N*S" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="text" name="sks1">
<input type="text" name="nilai1"> 
<input type="text" name="ns1" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="text" name="sks2">
<input type="text" name="nilai2">
<input type="text" name="ns2" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="text" name="sks3">
<input type="text" name="nilai3">
<input type="text" name="ns3" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="text" name="sks4">
<input type="text" name="nilai4">
<input type="text" name="ns4" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="text" name="sks5">
<input type="text" name="nilai5">
<input type="text" name="ns5" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="text" name="sks6">
<input type="text" name="nilai6">
<input type="text" name="ns6" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="text" name="totSks" placeholder="Jumlah SKS" disabled="">
<input type="text" disabled="">
<input type="text" name="totNilai" placeholder="IPS" disabled="">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="hitungIPS()">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

my js

```
function hitungIPS(){

    var sks1 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks1.value) || 0;
    var sks2 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks2.value) || 0;
    var sks3 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks3.value) || 0;
    var sks4 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks4.value) || 0;
    var sks5 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks5.value) || 0;
    var sks6 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks6.value) || 0;
    var nilai1 = document.ips.nilai1.value || 0;
    var nilai2 = document.ips.nilai2.value || 0;
    var nilai3 = document.ips.nilai3.value || 0;
    var nilai4 = document.ips.nilai4.value || 0;
    var nilai5 = document.ips.nilai5.value || 0;
    var nilai6 = document.ips.nilai6.value || 0;

    var totalSKS = sks1 + sks2 + sks3 + sks4 + sks5 + sks6;
        // nilaiSKS adalah N*S
    var nilaiSKS1 = sks1*n1;
    var nilaiSKS2 = sks2*nilai2;
    var nilaiSKS3 = sks3*nilai3;
    var nilaiSKS4 = sks4*nilai4;
    var nilaiSKS5 = sks5*nilai5;
    var nilaiSKS6 = sks6*nilai6;

    var totalNilai = nilaiSKS1 + nilaiSKS2 + nilaiSKS3 +nilaiSKS4 + nilaiSKS5 + nilaiSKS6;
    var totIPS = totalNilai / totalSKS;

    document.ips.totSks.value = totalSKS;
    document.ips.totNilai.value = totIPS;

    document.ips.ns1.value = nilaiSKS1;
    document.ips.ns2.value = nilaiSKS2;
    document.ips.ns3.value = nilaiSKS3;
    document.ips.ns4.value = nilaiSKS4;
    document.ips.ns5.value = nilaiSKS5;
    document.ips.ns6.value = nilaiSKS6;

    if ( nilai1.match("A") || nilai1.match("a")) {
        var n1 = '5';
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider using an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hitungIPS(){

var sks1 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks1.value) || 0;
var sks2 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks2.value) || 0;
var sks3 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks3.value) || 0;
var sks4 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks4.value) || 0;
var sks5 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks5.value) || 0;
var sks6 = parseFloat(document.ips.sks6.value) || 0;
var mappings = {
  'A': 5,
  'B': 4,
  'C': 3
};
var nilai1 = mappings[document.ips.nilai1.value] || 0;
var nilai2 = mappings[document.ips.nilai1.value] || 0;
var nilai3 = mappings[document.ips.nilai1.value] || 0;
var nilai4 = mappings[document.ips.nilai1.value] || 0;
var nilai5 = mappings[document.ips.nilai1.value] || 0;
var nilai6 = mappings[document.ips.nilai1.value] || 0;

var totalSKS = sks1 + sks2 + sks3 + sks4 + sks5 + sks6;
    // nilaiSKS adalah N*S
var nilaiSKS1 = sks1*nilai1;
var nilaiSKS2 = sks2*nilai2;
var nilaiSKS3 = sks3*nilai3;
var nilaiSKS4 = sks4*nilai4;
var nilaiSKS5 = sks5*nilai5;
var nilaiSKS6 = sks6*nilai6;

var totalNilai = nilaiSKS1 + nilaiSKS2 + nilaiSKS3 +nilaiSKS4 + nilaiSKS5 + nilaiSKS6;
var totIPS = totalNilai / totalSKS;

document.ips.totSks.value = totalSKS;
document.ips.totNilai.value = totIPS;

document.ips.ns1.value = nilaiSKS1;
document.ips.ns2.value = nilaiSKS2;
document.ips.ns3.value = nilaiSKS3;
document.ips.ns4.value = nilaiSKS4;
document.ips.ns5.value = nilaiSKS5;
document.ips.ns6.value = nilaiSKS6;
}
```

See http://codepen.io/mr_nameless/pen/LbwXbO
P.S. `If` statement would also work if you have put it right after `var nilai6 = document.ips.nilai1.value || 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the actual need. So, due to the lack of actual scenario, I am not able to understand your question properly.However, I concluded that you require a method that is able to convert A to 5 B to 4 and C to 3.
So that I have created a simple method that can DECODE your string I will explain it so that if you require to change it then you could.

```
    function DECODE(Str_Message) 
    {      
      SIMBOLOS = "ABC";

      Len_Simbolos = SIMBOLOS.length;   
      Len_Str_Message = Str_Message.length; 
      Str_Decoded_Message = "";      
      for (Position = 0; Position < Len_Str_Message; Position++)
      {                    
        Byte_To_Be_Decoded = Str_Message.charAt(Position);     
        Byte_Decoded = 0;          
        for (SecondPosition = 0; SecondPosition < Len_Simbolos;SecondPosition++) 
        {              
            Byte_To_Be_Compared = SIMBOLOS.charAt(SecondPosition);
            if (Byte_To_Be_Decoded == Byte_To_Be_Compared)
            {    
                if(Byte_To_Be_Decoded == SIMBOLOS[SecondPosition])
                {
                    Byte_Decoded = 5-SecondPosition;
                }   
              }          
         }          
         Str_Decoded_Message = Str_Decoded_Message+Byte_Decoded;      
       }      
       return Str_Decoded_Message;  
    }
```

Here, this DECODE function decodes your string character by character if it matched with SIMBOLOS string(here "ABC"). There I have applied two loops the first one for loop store the character relative to their position and second nested loop is the core of decoding method it store all the SIMBOLOS one by one and compare it to given string(for example: 'A') and if the SIMBOLOS is matched with string then it will apply a decoding technique(here position of string('A') in SIMBOLOS subtracted by 5) and then return the value.

Here is practical approach to this method:

```js
function DECODE(Str_Message) 
{      
  SIMBOLOS = "ABC";
  
     Len_Simbolos = SIMBOLOS.length;   
  Len_Str_Message = Str_Message.length; 
        Str_Decoded_Message = "";      
        for (Position = 0; Position < Len_Str_Message; Position++)
    {                    
            Byte_To_Be_Decoded = Str_Message.charAt(Position);     
            Byte_Decoded = 0;          
            for (SecondPosition = 0; SecondPosition < Len_Simbolos; SecondPosition++) 
   {              
                Byte_To_Be_Compared = SIMBOLOS.charAt(SecondPosition);
                if (Byte_To_Be_Decoded == Byte_To_Be_Compared)
     {    
     if(Byte_To_Be_Decoded == SIMBOLOS[SecondPosition])
     {
      Byte_Decoded = 5-SecondPosition;
     } 
                }          
            }          
   Str_Decoded_Message = Str_Decoded_Message+Byte_Decoded;      
        }      
        return Str_Decoded_Message;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#decod').on('click',function(){
     var valu = $('#deco').val();
     $("#output").text(DECODE(valu));
    });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="deco"></input>
  <button id="decod">decode</button>
  <div id="output"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function hitungIPS(){
    var mappings = {
      A: 5,
      B: 4,
      C: 3
    };
  
    var sks1 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("sks1")[0].value) || 0;
    var sks2 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("sks2")[0].value) || 0;
    var sks3 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("sks3")[0].value) || 0;
    var sks4 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("sks4")[0].value) || 0;
    var sks5 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("sks5")[0].value) || 0;
    var sks6 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("sks6")[0].value) || 0;
    var nilai1 = parseInt(mappings[document.getElementsByName("nilai1")[0].value.toUpperCase()]) || 0;
    var nilai2 = parseInt(mappings[document.getElementsByName("nilai2")[0].value.toUpperCase()]) || 0;
    var nilai3 = parseInt(mappings[document.getElementsByName("nilai3")[0].value.toUpperCase()]) || 0;
    var nilai4 = parseInt(mappings[document.getElementsByName("nilai4")[0].value.toUpperCase()]) || 0;
    var nilai5 = parseInt(mappings[document.getElementsByName("nilai5")[0].value.toUpperCase()]) || 0;
    var nilai6 = parseInt(mappings[document.getElementsByName("nilai6")[0].value.toUpperCase()]) || 0;
    
    
    var nilaiSKS1 = sks1*nilai1;
    var nilaiSKS2 = sks2*nilai2;
    var nilaiSKS3 = sks3*nilai3;
    var nilaiSKS4 = sks4*nilai4;
    var nilaiSKS5 = sks5*nilai5;
    var nilaiSKS6 = sks6*nilai6;

    var totalSKS = sks1 + sks2 + sks3 + sks4 + sks5 + sks6;
    var totalNilaiSks = nilaiSKS1 + nilaiSKS2 + nilaiSKS3 +nilaiSKS4 + nilaiSKS5 + nilaiSKS6;    
    var totalNilai = nilai1 + nilai2 + nilai3 + nilai4 + nilai5 + nilai6;    

    document.getElementsByName("totSks")[0].value = totalSKS;
    document.getElementsByName("totNilai")[0].value = totalNilai;
    document.getElementsByName("totNilaiSks")[0].value = totalNilaiSks;
  
    document.getElementsByName("ns1")[0].value = nilaiSKS1;
    document.getElementsByName("ns2")[0].value = nilaiSKS2;
    document.getElementsByName("ns3")[0].value = nilaiSKS3;
    document.getElementsByName("ns4")[0].value = nilaiSKS4;
    document.getElementsByName("ns5")[0].value = nilaiSKS5;
    document.getElementsByName("ns6")[0].value = nilaiSKS6;
}
```

```html
<form name="ips">
<div class="inputan">
<input type="number" value="SKS" disabled="">
<input type="text" value="Nilai" disabled="">
<input type="text" value="N*S" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="number" name="sks1">
<input type="text" name="nilai1"> 
<input type="text" name="ns1" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="number" name="sks2">
<input type="text" name="nilai2">
<input type="text" name="ns2" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="number" name="sks3">
<input type="text" name="nilai3">
<input type="text" name="ns3" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="number" name="sks4">
<input type="text" name="nilai4">
<input type="text" name="ns4" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="number" name="sks5">
<input type="text" name="nilai5">
<input type="text" name="ns5" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="number" name="sks6">
<input type="text" name="nilai6">
<input type="text" name="ns6" disabled="">
</div>
<div class="inputan">
<input type="text" name="totSks" placeholder="Jumlah SKS" disabled="">
<input type="text" name="totNilai" disabled="">
<input type="text" name="totNilaiSks" placeholder="IPS" disabled="">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="hitungIPS()">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Code dumps are not that useful. It would be better to add an explanation of what the problem was and how your proposed code fixes it.